# What is the gdrive callback url for a self hosted cartodb installation?

Tags: carto

I have a custom install of cartodb running on my own server. I need to integrate Google Drive with it.

I have set up an application on the Google Developers Console, but do not know what to insert for the callback url.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Supposing that you have installed cartodb on your server on:
http://yourdomain:3000/user/your_username/dashboard

You've to change this part of the file in config_app.yml to connect to google drive :

```
gdrive:
      application_name: 'your_appname'
      client_id:        'your_clientid'
      client_secret:    'myclient_secret'
      callback_url: 'http://yourdomain:3000/user/your_user/api/v1/imports/service/gdrive/oauth_callback'
```

You need to add the same callback url in "credential" on Google_drive website.

Hope that this helps

Answer (score 1):

This should be doable from the `app_config.yml` file, inside the oauth key:

```
  oauth:
    # If the client_id/app_key is not set won't appear at the UI. @see application_helper.rb -> frontend_config
    # Must be the same as CartoDB::Datasources::xxxx DATASOURCE_NAME constants
    gdrive:
      application_name:     ''
      client_id:            ''
      client_secret:        ''
      callback_url:         'whatever callback url'
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. What does the callback_url property have to be? Does it have to be a particular url?

Comment: Hi @iriberri - just to clarify my question. I am aware of the config file, but my question really is what should the callback_url be? On cartodb.com this seems to be set to a callback url that then closes the authentication window and brings the user back to the import data screen. Do I have to write my own endpoint with cartodb to handle this, or does it exist as part of the Google Drive import plugin?